# How to use OData from stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odata

How to use OData from stored procedure?

I have defined a controller like this

```
public class ReportOdataController : ODataController
{
    private DB_PLBEntities db = new DB_PLBEntities();

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Stp_Select_Report_Result> GetReportOdata()
    {
        return db.Stp_Select_Report(null).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

But when I call it through uri `/odata/ReportOdata?$inlinecount=allpages` it throws the following error :

> The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once.

I am new to programming so I don't understand why the error occurred or how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change(assuming `db`(`DB_PLBEntities`) is a `List<T>`) :

```
return db.Stp_Select_Report(null).AsQueryable();
```

To :

```
return db.Stp_Select_Report(null).AsQueryable().ToList();
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: but not return to IQueryable